# parsing Alpaca API objects into json

Tags: python, json, parsing

I am using the Alpaca API.

```
import alpaca_trade_api as tradeapi

api = tradeapi.REST('key1', 'key2', 'https://paper-api.alpaca.markets', 'v2')

#retrieve open positions
pos = api.list_positions()
pos
```

Output:

```
[Position({   'asset_class': 'us_equity',
     'asset_id': 'b0b6dd9d-8b9b-48a9-ba46-b9d54906e415',
     'avg_entry_price': '382.01',
     'change_today': '0.0025959042399769',
     'cost_basis': '382.01',
     'current_price': '382.36',
     'exchange': 'NASDAQ',
     'lastday_price': '381.37',
     'market_value': '382.36',
     'qty': '1',
     'side': 'long',
     'symbol': 'AAPL',
     'unrealized_intraday_pl': '0.35',
     'unrealized_intraday_plpc': '0.0009162063820319',
     'unrealized_pl': '0.35',
     'unrealized_plpc': '0.0009162063820319'})]
```

This has been my attempt:

```
pos[0]['asset_id']
>>>TypeError: 'Position' object is not subscriptable
```

How can I isolate the content stored in the Position object without transforming it into a string?

- `type(Position)` is `alpaca_trade_api.entity.Position`

Comment: As noted by the solution from @DYZ you must access the methods specific to `Position`. See [Easily visualize the correlation of your portfolio in Python](https://medium.com/automation-generation/easily-visualize-the-correlation-of-your-portfolio-in-python-alpaca-api-6c381274bcbd) and the Alpaca documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So many questions of this sort have been around in the past few days, I wonder what sparked so much interest in Alpaca. The answer is `pos[0].asset_id`: Alpaca objects have attributes, not keys.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
getattr(pos, 'asset_id')
```

I don't have positions, but it works the same as Asset:

```
a = api.get_asset('NFLX')
print(getattr(a, 'symbol'))
```